# How to add transparent images in java swt

Tags: java, eclipse, tree, swt, eclipse-rcp

I want to create an indented images
i have original image i want to add indentation to that image
so for that, i was creating one transparent image and using gc.drawImage i was trying to draw original image over it, but still white background is coming.

Is there any other way to add indentation to the original image in SWT tree.

Comment: Images can have a particular colour specified as the transparent colour. This is usually set up by loading the image from a format (such as GIF) that supports transparency.

Comment: how can i add indentation to the images in swt tree

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by indentation here. If you look at Package or Project Explorer in Eclipse images are indented to the level of tree item - these are just normal trees.

Comment: If you want to do complicated things with trees/tables in SWT maybe look at [nattable](https://eclipse.dev/nattable/)

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are asking. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), a screenshot what you actual get and tell what you want get instead. See also https://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/